# How to arrange money into funds, when funds can share expenses

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design, rdbms

If I am managing a club which has expenses (e.g. coffee, building repairs, electricity, cake, etc). Every time the club takes on an expense, then a record is added to the 'All Actual Expenses' table:

```
 ______________________      _______________________
|All Possible Expenses |    |All Actual Expenses    |
-----------------------      -----------------------
| ID                   |    | ID                    |
| Name of expense      |    | AllPossibleExpensesID |
-----------------------     | Date Occured          |
                            | Price                 |
                            -------------------------
```

Expenses can be arranged into funds (like 'Expenses of year 2017', 'Food Expenses', 'Expenses of business meeting held to discuss premises' etc.).

So the tables for funds is:

```
 ___________      _________________________________________
| Funds     |    | Funds LINK AllActualExpenses            |
------------|    |-----------------------------------------|
| Id        |    | FundID                                  |
| Fund Name |    | AllActualExpensesID that's in this fund |
------------      -----------------------------------------
```

As you can see, funds can 'overlap', so an expense can be part of a few funds.

When money is paid in to the club's coffers, the money can be allocated only to certain funds, like so:

```
_________________     _____________________________________
|Payments        |    | Payments LINK Funds                |
-----------------|    |------------------------------------|
| ID             |    | PaymentID                          |
| Date           |    | A FundID that this is allocated to |
| Amount Paid In |    -------------------------------------
| Member ID      |
-----------------|
```

This LOOKS good, but there's a problem I can't for the life of me work out what to do:

How do I show how much money each fund has in it? Remember, some money might be allocated to Funds ONE and TWO, while other money might be allocated to Funds TWO and THREE...so in reality, is there a good way to show how much money is in Funds ONE, how much money is in Fund TWO, and how much money is in Fund THREE?

The problem is, if the program simply shows how much money is in each fund, it will seem to the user that the club has far more money than it really has!

By extension, the following issues also crop up:

- What if some money isn't given to any funds...how will the program allocate it? How will the program show this money?
- If someone wants to give money towards certain expenses which aren't grouped in one fund alone, should I create a 'custom fund' for them? If I put the money straight towards the expenses, I will violate database theory (I think) because some money will be allocated direct to expenses and some money will be allocated to Funds!

I dunno, maybe I'm overlooking an obvious solution. Has this model been tackled before? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Your question seems too broad to me.  It would have been more effective if you just showed us a few tables with sample data, and then asked us how to perform a certain type of query.

Comment: thats pretty the question you asked a few days ago, isn't it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905841/database-design-how-do-i-allocate-money-to-different-funds-when-the-funds-can

Comment: @ Tim, I'm not here for the query to me made for me, I want ideas in how to design the model so I specifically made the question a bit broad.

Answer (score 0):

In "Payments Linked Expenses", you need to include an allocation column.  Then, your query looks like:

```
Select flae.fundID, sum(ae.Price * flae.allocation) as price 
from fundsLinkActualExpenses as flae join
     ActualExpenses as ae
    on flae.ExpensesID = flae.ExpensesID 
group by flae.fundID;
```

You will need to have triggers to ensure that the allocations add up to 100% when new expenses and funds and links are added.

Comment: I don't have a "payments Link Expenses" table, as I wrote in my question, I built the database to put money in the funds. Unless you think I should make a "payments Link Expenses" table? But then how will I make funds (which are very important to me)? ALSO, what does "flae" mean (pardon my ignorance)?

Answer (score 0):

if you have earnings and spendings   I think you should split them in partial amounts.

```
earning(id, amount)
    primary key: id
spending(id,amount)
    primary key: id
partial(earning_id,spending_id,amount)
    primary key: earning_id,spending_id
    foreign key: earning_id references earning(id)
    foreign key: spending_id references spending(id)

constraints:
     (sum(spending.amount) where spending.id=ARBITRARY_ID) 
         <= spending.amount where spending.id=ARBITRARY_ID
     where ARBITRARY_ID is a valid id from spending

     (sum(earning.amount) where earning.id=ARBITRARY_ID) 
         <= earning.amount where earning.id=ARBITRARY_ID
     where ARBITRARY_ID is a valid id from earning
```

so assume

```
spendings
id      amount
1        50
2       100
3       150
4        30

earnings
id      amount
1       100
2       100
3       120

parts
earning_id  spending_id amount
1           1           50
1           2           50
2           2           50
2           3           50
3           3          100
3           4           20
```

So we have

```
            payed by
spending    earning     remaining
1           1            0
2           1,2          0
3           2,3          0
4           3           10

            used for
earning     spending    remaining   
1           1,2         0
2           2,3         0
3           3,4         0
```

So we know exactly how the money is used.

The splitting into  the part amounts could be made manually, but of course it is better to use a subroutine. 
The subroutine can be executed by a trigger (this may be complex) or may be executed periodically.

---

In your design the earnings will be your payments and the spendings will be your expenses. The subroutine that splits the amounts has to take into account to which funds the payments were given.

If money will be given to funds as well as single expenses then both should have a common superclass. Lets call  it target (doubtlessly there will be better names).

So we have

```
target(id)
    primary key(id)

expenses(id
    primary key(id)
    foreign key(id) references target(id)

funds(id)
    primary key(id)
    foreign key(id) references target(id)

money is not given to funds  or expenses but to targets.
```

Comment: This is good, but I wanted to go a step further: without allocating earnings to expenses, just earnings to funds, is there a good way to make good queries/designs for the program to show how much money is available _per fund_? Also, I don't see the point of "Targets" - I mean, each time the user wants to pay just to expenses, he can make a Custom Fund of those expenses! Seems easier, no?